# Where the component gets mounted into, when we hit componentDidMount in react? is it real DOM or VirtualDom?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle-hooks

When will you hit the componentDidMount hook in react? is it when the component is mounted to the virtual dom or actual dom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component is mounted to the Virtual DOM on `render()`, at the "Render phase".

The `componentDidMount` lifecycle, which is part of the "Commit phase", is mounted to the actual DOM.

Notice that you can have another render phase if you call `setState` in the `componentDidMount`.

> You may call `setState()` immediately in `componentDidMount()`. It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen.

- [React lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).
- [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)
- [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
- [Built your own React.](https://pomb.us/build-your-own-react/)

Comment: So componentDidMount will trigger soon after the component is mounted to the virtual dom? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Soon after, yes

Comment: One last question, so after triggering componentDidMount that specific node of the Virtual DOM will sync with real DOM in reconciliation. Is that what happens behind the scene?

Comment: Yes, this what happens.